# Keycloak User Attributes are empty after integration with Okta SAML Provider

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, keycloak, okta, openid-connect

I have configured Keycloak with Okta SAML Provider.
Unfortunately, the User Attributes are empty.
I have values in Okta but the in Keycloak values are empty.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Okta to add the User Attributes to the SAML assertion and then you need to configure Keycloak to add these Attributes to the user.
Read the post for details https://ultimatesecurity.pro/post/okta-update-user/